# Anchored images disappear after script replaces text

Tags: adobe-indesign

I have a script that changes the encoding of an Indic document to Unicode by iterating over `textStyleRanges`.  The encoding change is based on existing well-tested JS code and works great except that the anchors/text-colors all move or disappear on conversion.

**Before -**
[image]

**After -**
[image]

Are there fixes/alternatives to convert the encoding and also preserve the anchors?

```js
    function ascii2unicode(text){
        var words = text.split(' ');
    
        // To stote converted words
        var op_words = [];
    
        // Process and append to main array
        words.forEach(function(word, k, arr){
            op_words.push('mwe-text');                      
        });
    
        // Return converted line
        return op_words.join(' ');
    }
    
    var doc = app.activeDocument;
    var stories = doc.stories;
    var textStyleRanges = stories.everyItem().textStyleRanges.everyItem().getElements();
    
    for (var i = textStyleRanges.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        var myText = textStyleRanges[i];
        if (myText.appliedFont.fontFamily.toLowerCase().indexOf('nudi') == 0) { 
            var converted = ascii2unicode(myText.contents);
            if (myText.contents != converted) {  
                myText.contents = "";                 
                myText.appliedFont = app.fonts.item("Tunga");
                myText.contents = converted; 
                myText.composer="Adobe World-Ready Paragraph Composer";
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried removing these two lines: `myText.contents = "";` and `myText.contents = converted;`?

Comment: Tried removing the first as the second is what the script is all about. Didn't help. Thanks for the time.

Comment: If all you want to change is the appliedFont and the composer, you should not need to change the content. But the second line is, I believe the cause of your problems.

Comment: Yes, the second line is the cause and the primary purpose of the script. The font and composer change are secondary. The composer in particular is not essential. Thanks

Comment: So, is the problems solved? If it's not I'd propose to iterate not through `textStyleRanges` but through `Characters` and skip the characters that have  `pageItems.length > 0`. Surely it will work slower, but I think it preserves the anchored items. Probably it's possible to combine the two approaches: try to convert the textStyleRanges first, but for the ranges with pageItems inside switch to the slower algorithm and process the characters separately.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this problem, you can try using the following code:

```
var doc = app.activeDocument;
var stories = doc.stories;
var textStyleRanges = stories.everyItem().textStyleRanges.everyItem().getElements();

for (var i = textStyleRanges.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
    var myText = textStyleRanges[i];
    if (myText.appliedFont.fontFamily.toLowerCase().indexOf('nudi') == 0) {
        var converted = ascii2unicode(myText.contents);
        if (myText.contents != converted) {
            var myAnchor = myText.anchoredObjectSettings[0];
            var myColor = myText.fillColor;
            myText.contents = "";
            myText.appliedFont = app.fonts.item("Tunga");
            myText.contents = converted;
            myText.composer="Adobe World-Ready Paragraph Composer";
            myText.anchoredObjectSettings[0] = myAnchor;
            myText.fillColor = myColor;
        }
    }
}
```

The code above will preserve the anchored object and the text color. Because the anchored object is a property of the text frame, you need to set it after the text frame is created. The same is true for the text color.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am seeing the Error String: Object does not support the property or method 'anchoredObjectSettings'. Should I call use the property differently?